# PowerShell: How to add 1 user to multiple Active Directory Security Groups - Security tab of the security group with write permission

Tags: powershell, active-directory, powershell-4.0, network-security-groups

I am trying to add 1 ID to multiple security groups in Active Directory.
The ID needs to be only added to the "Security Tab" of the Security Group and not added as a member.

I need to set "write" permission for this ID.

Is there anyways to do this in Power-Shell?

[image: Security Tab]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are instructions [here](https://richardspowershellblog.wordpress.com/2011/06/29/setting-security-permissions-on-an-ad-group/), although that gives a user full control of the group (including rights to delete), and has some other issues (like a hard-coded username).

I've modified that example for you to only give [`GenericWrite`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.activedirectoryrights) permissions, and to accept the username as a parameter. This also assumes the user, group, and computer you're running this on are all on the same domain:

```
function Set-GroupSecurity {
[CmdletBinding()]
param (
 [string] $GroupName,
 [string] $UserName
)
    $dom = [System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.Domain]::GetCurrentDomain()
    $root = $dom.GetDirectoryEntry()

    $search = [System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher]$root
    $search.Filter = "(&(objectclass=group)(sAMAccountName=$GroupName))"
    $search.SizeLimit = 3000
    $result = $search.FindOne()

    $object = $result.GetDirectoryEntry()

    $sec = $object.ObjectSecurity

    ## set the rights and control type
    $allow = [System.Security.AccessControl.AccessControlType]::Allow
    $read = [System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectoryRights]::GenericRead
    $write = [System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectoryRights]::GenericWrite

    ## who does this apply to
    $domname = ([ADSI]"").Name
    $who = New-Object -TypeName System.Security.Principal.NTAccount -ArgumentList "$domname", $UserName

    # apply rules
    $readrule = New-Object -TypeName System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectoryAccessRule -ArgumentList $who, $read, $allow
    $sec.AddAccessRule($readrule)

    $writerule = New-Object -TypeName System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectoryAccessRule -ArgumentList $who, $write, $allow
    $sec.AddAccessRule($writerule)

    # tell it that we're only changing the DACL and not the owner
    $object.get_Options().SecurityMasks = [System.DirectoryServices.SecurityMasks]::Dacl

    # save
    $object.CommitChanges()
}
```

You can paste that into a PowerShell prompt and hit enter. That will make the function available to use. Then you can use it like this:

```
Set-GroupSecurity -GroupName "TstGroup1" -UserName "someone"
```

Comment: Much appreciate your help! Thank you! I just gave it a try but I got below error. I am learning PS and still don't know this one...

Exception calling "CommitChanges" with "0" argument(s): "A constraint violation occurred.
"
At line:30 char:5
+     $object.CommitChanges()
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException

Comment: I found a description of that issue [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1283a2d0-0c76-442c-af4b-db255bca3215/assign-rights-to-the-user-group-for-particular-ou-in-active-directory-using-c#676841e7-66f0-4d5f-9491-f5db7ba34185-isAnswer). I updated the code in my answer. Now that I can actually test this, I also realized the Read permission needs to be set separately too, so I added that.

Comment: Thank you very much! This was a great help. hope the good deed comes back to you very soon! :)